# sql increase time shown

Tags: php, mysql, sql, time, timezone

I have a script that adds content in my mysql database with a date/time stamp. It's not possible to change the input date/time for me.

i want the date-time changed when i query out of my mysql database.

cell in my db: 2016-08-17 17:34:29

It needs to be: 2016-08-17 19:34:29 ( so +02:00 hour in the php page shown to visitors)

I cannot UPDATE the time in de database because other applications depend on the data in the current format.

Thanks in advance!

Website coding now:

```
<?PHP
//make connection
mysql_connect('localhost','user','pass');

//select db
mysql_select_db('database');

?>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    </head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>disappear_time</th>
</tr>
<?php
$query_150="
SELECT * FROM `table` 
WHERE `disappear_time` > SUBDATE( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 2 HOUR)
AND `id` = 150
ORDER BY `disappear_time` DESC";
$150 = mysql_query($query_150) or die(mysql_error());
while($row_150 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_150)){
  //handle rows.
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row_150['id']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row_150['disappear_time']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";}
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding 2 hours to the `disappear_time` in your `SELECT` statement?

Comment: Whats the best way to do that?

Comment: Is `disappear_time` what contains the datetime you need to add 2 hours to and show to the user?

Comment: yes, it is, its the column in the table.

Comment: So why not use `SELECT id, DATE_ADD(disappear_time, INTERVAL 2 HOUR) AS disappear_time` instead of `SELECT *`? That way you're modifying the date in your resultset before it's displayed on the website and you're not changing the datetime in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! answer is:

```
SELECT id2, DATE_ADD(disappear_time, INTERVAL 2 HOUR) AS disappear_time FROM `table` 
WHERE `disappear_time` > SUBDATE( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 2 HOUR)
AND `id` = 147
ORDER BY `disappear_time` ASC";
```